# One Activity, multiple Fragments and setRetainInstance

Tags: android, android-fragments

in my app I'm using one activity and two fragments. The app uses a layout with a container so the fragments are added via transactions. The first fragment contains a listview and the other fragment a detail view for the listview items.
Both fragments use setRetainInstance(true). The fragments are added via a replace transaction and addToBackStack(null) is set. The listfragment contains an instance variable which holds some infos for the list. Now I'm changing to detail and press back and the instance variable is null. I read about setRetainInstance and addToBackStack and removed addToBackStack, but even then the instance variable is null.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setRetainInstance(true)` will tell the `FragmentManager` to keep the fragment around when the containing `Activity` is killed and rebuilt for some reason.  It doesn't guarantee that the `Fragment` instance will stick around after a transaction to add or replace.  It sounds like your adapter is being garbage collected and you're not creating a new one.

A more generally easy solution would be to make a viewless `Fragment` to retain your `ListAdapter`.  The way you do this is to create the `Fragment`, set the retain instance to true, and return `null` in the method `onCreateView()`. To add it, just called `addFragment(Fragment, String)` via the `FragmentTransaction`. You never remove or replace it, so it will always stay in memory for the length of the app.  Screen rotations won't kill it.

Whenever your `ListFragment` is created, in `onCreateView()` get the `FragmentManager` and use either the method `findFragmentById()` or `FindFragmentByTag()` to retrieve your retained fragment from memory.  Then get the adapter from that fragment and set it as your adapter for the list.

```
public class ViewlessFragment extends Fragment {

   public final static string TAG = "ViewlessFragment";

   private ListAdapter mAdapter;

   @Override
   public ViewlessFragment() {
      mAdapter = createAdater();
      setRetainInstance(true);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      return null;
   }

   public ListAdapter getAdapter() {
      return mAdapter;
   }
}

public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

   final public static String TAG = "MyListFragment";

   @Override
   public void onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      final View returnView = getMyView();
      final ViewlessFragment adapterFragment = (ViewlessFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ViewlessFragment.TAG);
      setListAdapter(ViewlessFragment.getAdapter());
      return returnView;
   }
}

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
      // ... setup code...
      final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
      final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
      ViewlessFragment adapterFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(ViewlessFragment.TAG);
      if(adapterFragment == null) {
         ft.add(new ViewlessFragment(), ViewlessFragment.TAG);
      }
      ft.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, new MyListFragment(), MyListFragment.TAG);
      ft.commit();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea,viewless fragment sounds good. will try this this evening.

Comment: So this viewless fragment runs parallel to the currently shown fragment and provides the info when needed, right?

Comment: "runs parallel" is bad terminology in a programming perspective, but yes. It remains in memory because you never remove it from the `FragmentManager`.  Since the adapter and adapter's data is created in the constructor, it's only created once when you make a new instance.  Then just call `getAdapter()` to retrieve that adapter.  The data is going to be around whenever a new `ListView` is inflated for any reason.

Comment: While it is technically working, I still wonder whether it is a good idea to use Fragments as a means of storing 'global' information. Just using a Application subclass or even use static members sounds like less overhead?

Comment: Possibly, but you get a bit more control if you use a Fragment.  You can subclass Fragments for example.  You encapsulate the information which easily allows for maintenance.  It remove tight coupling.  It all depends on your needs.  Overall, direct access will always remove overhead though.

Comment: One caveat with this approach: make sure that you're not leaking memory during orientation changes. I've been testing this with the new `RecyclerView` and the adapter held in the fragment was keeping references to the UI views, which in turn were keeping references to the activity. My fix to this issue was to call `recyclerView.setAdapter(null)` in the UI fragment's `onDestroyView()`.